# Vue 3 split an array into 2 columns

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3

Good day,

I am trying to split and Axios request into 2 columns when above 720px and 1 column when under 720px.
I managed to achieve this by using CSS with some height: 200vh, display flex, and so on to force it to split into 2 columns, but this is not the correct approach.
There is a way of doing it with computed propriety but I just can't get it to work.

My full code is below:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="getPosts" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mb-5">
      Load List
    </button>
    <h4 v-if="errorMsg">{{ errorMsg }}</h4>
    <!-- <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <tbody class="list__wrapper">
        <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
          <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col" v-for="column in columns" :key="column.id">
        <div class="item-container" v-for="post in column" :key="post.id">
          {{ post.title }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "PostList",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errorMsg: "",
      cols: 2,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    columns() {
      let columns = [];
      let mid = Math.ceil(this.post.length / this.cols);
      for (let col = 0; col < this.cols; col++) {
        columns.push(this.post.slice(col * mid, col * mid + mid));
      }
      return columns;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errorMsg = "Error retrieving data";
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}
.list {
  list-style: none;
}
.list__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* height: 510vh; */
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #759c99;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  tbody {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }
  .list__wrapper {
    /* height: 150vh; */
  }
}

/* test */
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.col {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item-container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it eventualy from CSS:

```
.list__wrapper {
display: block;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 40px;
column-rule: 1px double #759c99;
```

}